# I have a react app and godaddy shared hosting which supports python app ... Can I deploy the server on the python app?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, contact-form, shared-hosting

I'm currently configuring the contact form for my React app. Initially, I utilized Express and Nodemailer and tested it on a local server, where it functioned properly. However, upon gaining access to the hosting service, I discovered that it was a GoDaddy shared hosting, which does not support node apps. Consequently, I uploaded the React app, and for the server, I'm attempting to set up a Python app to handle the deployment. Presently, I encounter an issue where the app deploys to a development server and displays 'localhost:5000.' Unfortunately, when I attempt to open this link, it shows a 'page not found' error. Despite trying various solutions, I have been unable to find a resolution. Could you please let me know if there are any mistakes I might be making? This project marks my first experience with React and the implementation of a contact form. If there are any alternative approaches that are easier to implement, I would greatly appreciate your suggestions. I have already explored Email JS and mailtrap, but they do not meet my requirements.

```
*****@***** [~/*****]$ python server.py
 * Serving Flask app 'server'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```